# I'm trying to implement trees DS in python and cannot make sense of what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, tree

This is the code i've used.

**Node Class**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.data = val
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None
```

class Tree:

```
def __init__(self,val):
    self.root = Node(val)
    self.head = self.root
```

**#Insert Function**

```
    def insert(self,val):
        head = self.root
        if head:
            if val > head.data:
                if not head.rightChild:
                    head.rightChild = Tree(val)
                    print("{} inserted in Right Tree".format(val))
                else:
                    head.rightChild.insert(val)
            elif val < head.data:
                if not head.leftChild:
                    head.leftChild = Tree(val)
                    print("{} inserted in Left Tree".format(val))
                else:
                    head.leftChild.insert(val)
```

## Traversal Functions

```
def inorder(self): 
    head = self.head
    if head:
        head.leftChild.inorder() #line 33
        print(head.data) #line 34
        head.rightChild.inorder() #line 35
```

There is something clearly wrong here coz when I execute main function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input("Enter the value for the root node : "))
    a = list(map(int,input("Enter the values to be inserted in the tree : ").split()))
    root = Tree(5)
    for i in a:
        root.insert(i)
    #print(root.data) #line 56
    #print(root.leftChild.data) #line 57
    #print(root.rightChild.data) #line 58
    #root.inorder() #line59
```

These are the errors i'm getting :

1. On running print(root.data), print(root.leftChild) and root.(rightChild)

> ```
> Enter the value for the root node : 5
> Enter the values to be inserted in the tree : 1 6
> 1 inserted in Left Tree
> 6 inserted in Right Tree
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "trees.py", line 56, in <module>
>     print(root.data)
> AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'data'
> ```

2. On running root.inorder()

> ```
> Enter the value for the root node : 5
> Enter the values to be inserted in the tree : 1 6
> 1 inserted in Left Tree
> 6 inserted in Right Tree
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "trees.py", line 59, in <module>
>     root.inorder()
>   File "trees.py", line 33, in inorder
>     head.leftChild.inorder()
>   File "trees.py", line 33, in inorder
>     head.leftChild.inorder()
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'inorder'
> ```

Can someone please elaborate what am I doing wrong and what I should be doing instead. Also why am I wrong ( if possible ).

Comment: The error says data isn’t there. Your problem is data isn’t there.

Comment: You should try printing `root.head.data` because `root` is an instance of `Tree` class and it doesn't have `data` attribute. Same goes for printing data for left child or right child.

Comment: @Jonathan I didn't get you. Like i'm passing the values and they are getting inserted as well. So I'm sorry but I didn't quite got you. You can try running the code and let me know the changes to be made. That will help a lot. :)

Comment: @user13242043 which error is the same? The first one or the second one? And, where did you change this code. I expect on line no 56, 57 and 58.

Comment: @AKS Thanks man this helped. Yeah now i know what was the mistake i was doing. I was considering root = Tree(n) as the root inside of tree. Whereas it was root.root.data. Thanks. I guess i got confused in the namings. XD
Can you help me with the traversal function

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: Yes, how can i mark it closed ? So that people know it's been solved. 
Or should I just delete it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Tree classes **init** should  should look something like this:

```
class Tree:

    def __init__(self,val):
        self.data = val # value here
        self.leftChild =  # insert left chile here
        self.rightChild = # insert right child here

        
        self.root = Node(val)
        self.head = self.root
```

you were trying to get data from class Tree when you hadn't mentioned the value data in inside the class
Same goes with leftchild and right child

Comment: solving the above mentioned issues is more than likely going to fix the inorder fxn

Comment: shouldn't it be self.root = Tree(val) ?
And my root is an instance of Node class so is it not valid thing. Like root will inherit data, leftChild and rightChild of node right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your inorder function checks if head is `NONE` but what if head's left or right child is `NONE` and then you are calling `.inorder()` to `NONE` which is throwing an error.

And for data you should use `root.head.data` instead of `root.data` as tree object don't have any data variable.

Comment: I have tested `root.head.data` in my local setup and it's working perfectly fine

Comment: I think it will not enter the loop if leftchild or rightchild is none because on calling head.leftchild.inorder(), i guess head = leftChild and hence violating the property of if condition. correct me if i'm wrong. I'm saying to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Suppose you have only one node that is 5 so your code will go in `inorder()` and check if head is not `NONE` which is not as head is 5 but after checking it will directly take `head.leftchild` which is `NONE` here and then it will do `NONE.inorder()` which will throw an error.

Comment: ohhh ok. Thanks now I understand it fully.

Answer (score 0):

As to the errors:

> `print(root.data)`
> AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'data'

This shows a mix-up in your code: `Node` class instances have the `data` attribute, not the `Tree` class instance. So if you want to display the root's data, you should reference:

```
root.head.data
```

However, more of your code is suffering from this mix up. See the second part of my answer.

> `head.leftChild.inorder()`
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'inorder'

This happens because you did not first check whether `head.leftChild` is maybe `None`. Your code only checked that `head` was not `None`, but sometimes `head.leftChild` will be `None`.

### Other problems / remarks

1. `elif val < head.data:` will skip values when already present

   When the value to insert is already in the tree, it will be skipped. If this is your purpose, then it is fine. If however, you want your tree to accept and store duplicate values, this should be just `else:`.
2. The `Tree` class should not define both a `root` and a `head` member.

   They are equivalent in meaning -- you should only keep one. As this is a *tree*, it sounds more logical to choose `root` as a name. `head` is more commonly used as a name in linked list implementations.
3. The constructor of `Tree` should not create a root node.

   A tree can have 0 nodes. This is a valid concept. So the `Tree` constructor should not require that you pass a value for the root node. It should just create the instance without any node, initialising the `root` as `None`.
4. The `insert` method should not create other `Tree` instances.

   It should create `Node` instances directly. Your implementation is going to create a `Tree` instance for every value, which in turn creates a single `Node` for each. This is overkill and costs a lot more memory than needed. The idea is to create *one* `Tree` instance, and 0 or more `Node` instances.
5. Define an `insert` method on `Node`.

   Because of the previous point, and because you have designed your `insert` method to be recursive (which is fine), you should define it on the `Node` class. The `Tree` class will then just have a simple `insert` method that calls the method with the same name on the `root` member.
6. Define an `inorder` method on `Node`.

   The same principle as above: as `inorder` is recursive and you'll want to iterate *Nodes*, define it on the `Node` class.
7. Methods should not be designed to *print*.

   Printing is something that should be kept separate from such data structure implementations (except when you need to debug). Instead of having `inorder` print, make it **yield** the values. That way the caller can decide freely what they want to do with the values.

Here is a version of your code that takes the above points into account:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.data = val
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

    def insert(self, val):  # Define on Node class
        if val > self.data:
            if not self.rightChild:
                self.rightChild = Node(val)  # You should create a Node
            else:
                self.rightChild.insert(val)
        else:  # Also store duplicates (if that is what you want)
            if not self.leftChild:
                self.leftChild = Node(val)
            else:
                self.leftChild.insert(val)

    def inorder(self): 
        if self.leftChild:
            yield from self.leftChild.inorder()
        yield self.data   # Don't print. Yield!
        if self.rightChild:
            yield from self.rightChild.inorder()


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):  # No value argument
        # No need for both a head and a root member
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, val):
        if self.root:
            self.root.insert(val)  # Let the Node class do the job
        else:
            self.root = Node(val)  # First node

    def inorder(self): 
        if self.root:
            yield from self.root.inorder()  # Let the Node class do the job
```

You could then use it as:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
tree = Tree()  # Create an instance of the tree without arguments
for val in data:
    tree.insert(val)
# Iterate the values of the tree, and print them.
print(*tree.inorder())
```